# Firebase push на Android: MismatchSenderId

Tags: android, api, firebase

Зарегался в Ferebase, настроил приложение (положил куда надо google-services.json и прописал что надо в build.gradle). Приложение успешно привязалось. Все соответствующие пермишны сделал, приложение успешно генерит нужный токен.

Во вкладке "Cloud Messaging" скопировал ключ и делаю запрос на https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send с заголовками:

```
Authorization key=КЛЮЧ
Content-Type application/json
```

И телом:

```
{
  "to": "ТОКЕН_УСТРОЙСТВА",
  "notification": {
    "title": "Title", 
    "body": "Message"
  },
  "data": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
}
```

В ответ упорно получаю:

```
{
  "multicast_id": ЦИФЕРКИ,
  "success": 0,
  "failure": 1,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "error": "MismatchSenderId"
    }
  ]
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Выглядит всё правильно. Но не видно как именно вы получаете токен  - покажите этот код. И поясните, как вы его потом используете - может вы его на сервер отсылаете и на этом этапе с ним что-то происходит? Или просто в логи выводите и оттуда в Postman/curl копируете?

Comment: Токен получаю по событию: PushNotification.configure({ onRegister: token => console.log("TOKEN:", token, ... (это react-native-push-notifications https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification).Токен я смотрю просто через adb shell logcat | grep token:, то есть он априори верный и если бы он был не верный, то ошибка была бы другой: InvalidRegistration

Comment: Ого как сложно) Боюсь, ничего не смогу подсказать - не знаю как это в вашем фреймворке сделано. Возможно, вы не всё из доки сделали. Я вижу там поминание SenderId `senderID: "YOUR GCM (OR FCM) SENDER ID",` - у вас оно сделано? Дополните вопрос информацией о фреймворке, либах и коде.

Comment: Вы меня просто спасли, вот параметр senderID я то и не углядел: он остался дефолтным. В этом то и было дело.

Comment: Рад был помочь)